Automate sending CSV file to Sharepoint
We created a Python code to query a database and bring the data into a CSV file. My question is how and what is the best way to automate sending to Sharepoint? I'm kind of new in this area and wanted to do some cool automation; The tools used in the code are enough to do it? There's something wrong with this approach?
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from Executers.select import Selects
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext



def upload_to_sharepoint(file_path, sharepoint_url, sharepoint_folder, client_id, client_secret):
 # SharePoint authentication
 credentials = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)
 ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(credentials)



 # Path and file name
 with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
 target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sharepoint_folder)
 target_file = target_folder.upload_file(os.path.basename(file_path), file)
ctx.execute_query()
print(f"File '{file_path}' successfully uploaded to SharePoint.")



def main():
# CSV file path
output_path = 'path/to/save/csv'
os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)
csv_file = os.path.join(output_path, 'annual_result.csv')



# Parameters for SQL query (last 24 hours)
yesterday = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')



# SQL query for the last 24 hours 24 hours
selects = Selects()
script = f""" SELECT ................... (not allowed to display)
"""

# Execute the query and receive new data
df_new = selects.execute_query(script)

# Check if the CSV already exists to accumulate data
if os.path.exists(csv_file):
df_existing = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df_updated = pd.concat([df_existing, df_new]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
else:
df_updated = df_new

# Save the updated DataFrame in the CSV
df_updated.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
print(f"CSV updated and saved in {csv_file}")

# Parameters for connection and SharePoint folder
sharepoint_url = "https://suaconta.sharepoint.com/sites/seusite"
 sharepoint_folder = "/sites/yoursite/Documentos%20Shared/your_folder"
 client_id = "your_client_id"
 client_secret = "your_client_secret"

 # Upload to SharePoint
 upload_to_sharepoint(csv_file, sharepoint_url, sharepoint_folder, client_id, client_secret)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()


I will recommend you to use rest api to upload a csv file bu following code
"""
Demonstrates how to upload a CSV file to a SharePoint site
"""

import os

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_team_site_url, test_user_credentials

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_user_credentials)

list_title = "Documents"
folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
path = "../../data/Financial Sample.csv"
with open(path, "r") as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read().encode("utf-8-sig")
file = folder.upload_file(os.path.basename(path), file_content).execute_query()
print("File has been uploaded into: {0}".format(file.serverRelativeUrl))

